# How to read Firestore field value in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to get field value.
[image]

my code is..

```html
void _checkNumner(String number) async {
    final userRef = firestore.collection('users');
    var documentSnapshot =
        await userRef.where("number", isEqualTo: true).get().then((num) {
      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> number = num;

      print(number);
      print("test");
    });
    print(documentSnapshot);
  }
```

but my console is

[image]

how I get field number?
I want to load number values ​​in all docs.
I'm so beginer. T.T

Please reply from the masters
Thank you

Comment: Why are you checking the `"number"` field with a boolean in your `where` clause? Remove this and use `number.docs.first.get("number")`. For better readability rename `number` to `data`

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase firestore is a NoSQL, document-oriented database. User Data is stored in documents which are organized into collection , i.e collection contains list of document. In simpler words we can say QuerySnapshot contains/provide group of DocumentSnapshot. [more about firestore data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) [image]
**Collection --> QuerySnapshot --> Group of DocumentSnapshot

Document --> DocumentSnapshot**

### 1) Fetch from collection - QuerySnapshot

Here we'll get list of DocumentSnapshots, we can filter by using where commad

```
Future<void> checkNumber(int number) async {
    final QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where("number", isEqualTo: number)
        .get();
    snapshot.docs.isEmpty
        ? {
            //TODO: your code here
            debugPrint("no data found")
          }
        : {
            for (DocumentSnapshot element in snapshot.docs)
              {
                //TODO: your code here
                debugPrint("number is: ${element['number']}"),
                debugPrint("name is: ${element['name']}"),
              }
          };
  }
```

### 1) Fetch from document - DocumentSnapshot

To fetch data from document we require documentId, and we get a single documentSnapshot instead of multiple like in above way.

```
  Future<void> checkNumberWithDocId() async {
    const String docId = 'aaaa';
    final DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(docId).get();
    snapshot.exists
        ? {
            //TODO: your code here
            debugPrint("no data found")
          }
        : {
            //TODO: your code here
            debugPrint("number is: ${snapshot['number']}"),
            debugPrint("name is: ${snapshot['name']}"),
          };
  }
```